# How to extract key and value from json column in Postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I want to add key-value pairs extracted from json column to table with Postgresql.

I have an items_table with uid and data column in json with multiple pairs. Initial table that looks like:

```
uid | data

1   | {"item1":"string1", "item2":"string2"}
2   | {"item2":"string3", "item5":"string1", "item7":"string5"}
3   | {"item1":"string3", "item4":"string1", "item6":"string8", "item5":"string5"}
4   | {"item1":"string4"}
```

...

Thus, some items/strings can repeat and fields length can vary as well.

I tried apply jsonb_object_keys, mentioned in documentation, however I occurred an error.

```
     select jsonb_object_keys(data) 
     from items_table;
```

**ERROR**: *function jsonb_object_keys(character varying) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts*.

I would like obtain a table result in following way to get split by items and strings, expanding uid column:

```
uid | items      | strings

1   | item1      | string1
1   | item2      | string2
2   | item2      | string3
2   | item5      | string1
2   | item7      | string5
3   | item1      | string3
3   | item4      | string1
3   | item6      | string8
3   | item5      | string5
4   | item1      | string4
```

How is it possible to achieve the above output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_each_text()` method to easily split `jsonb` type column to two seperate columns :

```
select uid, (js).key as items, (js).value as strings
  from
  (
   select uid, jsonb_each_text(data) as js
     from tab
  ) q
```

or more directly by using `cross join` :

```
select uid, js.items, js.value as strings
  from tab
 cross join jsonb_each_text(data) as js(items)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=bfd1fdb0abf95d7b8ae1dfaba7a35a18)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to extract the keys and then the values:

```
select key, v.j->key
from (values (1, '{"item1":"string1", "item2":"string2"}'::jsonb),
             (2, '{"item2":"string3", "item5":"string1", "item7":"string5"}'::jsonb)
     ) v(id, j) cross join lateral
     jsonb_object_keys(v.j) as key;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b9de6c6f3a2119fa07ef6ccc69f7eb7e) is a db<>fiddle.